Computer Vision for Finding matching wood molding profiles
I am trying to build a Python program that takes a tracing of the profile of a wood molding as input and then searches through a directory containing several hundred molding profile line drawings to find the closest match(es). I'm very new to computer vision and pretty new to Python (I have worked extensively in other programming languages). I've tried several methods so far but none have given results that are even close to acceptable. I think it may be because these are simple line drawings and I am using the wrong techniques
A (very clean example) of an input would be:
Input Tracing
With the closest match being:
Matching Line Drawing
My goal is that someone could upload a picture of the tracing of their molding profile and have the program find the closest matches available. Most input images would be rougher that this and could be submitted at various angles and resolutions.
It wouldn't matter if the program returned a similar shape that was smaller of larger, I can filter the results once I know what matches were found.
This is a project that I am using to learn Python and Computer Vision so I have no real deadline.
I am grateful for any input you can offer to help me complete this project.
Thank you.

take a look at the opencv module. this should do what you need.

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python
